# Regex to capture the multiple words from errorString

Tags: java, regex, regex-group

I have String which is basically containing the error information, I want to capture the important information from the error string

I have below error String.

```
trackingID=jskdf-77sdkj-oij4-kerj43-lklfds; 
key1=lksfjsdkjfkslkdjf;
key2=skjfjdkfj43jrkjskd;
key3=lksfjsdkjfkslkdjf;
key4=skjfjdkfj43jrkjskd;


{
    "info":{
      "details":[
         {
            "code":"ABC23423",
            "messages":"msg:INVALID_ERROR",
            "timeStamp":"2019-08-30T15:03:43.668Z"
         }
      ],
      "$httpStatus":400
   },
   "status":400,
   "test":"ABC2342fdsff3",
   "contactDetails":{
      "primaryCommunication":{
         "addressLine1":"231 London 71",
         "addressLine2":"",
         "addressLine3":"",
         "city":"London",
         "country":"England",
         "countryCode":"GB",
         "postalCode":"TW33ER",
         "usage":"Home",
         "county":"ENGLAND",
         "stateCode":"",
         "state":""
      },
      "name":{
         "number":"45765767343",
         "title":"Mr",
         "firstName":"Nitin",
         "lastName":"Dumbre",
         "address":"nitin-d@gmail.com",
         "code":"+44"
      },
      "email":{
         "address":"nitin-d@gmail.come"
      },
      "phone":[
         {
            "number":"44 7647632746732",
            "code":"Home"
         }
      ],
      "preferredCountry":{
         "code":""
      },
      "preferredLanguage":""
   }
}
```

And I want to capture below attributes values:

1. trackingID
2. code
3. messages
4. status

I have formed below Regex to capture these details

```
(trackingID|\\"code|\"messages|\"status\\")(=|\\":\\"|:)([^(;|\\"|,)]*)
```

Above regex is not working in all the cases. for an example in given the string `\"code\":\"` is coming in multiple times, Hence the code values is getting override.

I want to capture the value **code** attribute which is coming before the `\"messages\":\"` attribute.

Could you please help me to improve the regex?

Comment: I think you need a json parser in your problem instead of a regex

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem you could use the GSON instead of the REGEX it will be more clean and less complex solution.

Comment: This should be a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed that using a JSON parser would be clean, however, not all your `String` is JSON so you need some kind of parsing to extract the `TrackingId` anyways and also to extract the JSON string itself before you can parse it to a `Map` or some object you have.

I wouldn't bother and just go line by line and identify the lines I want by its start, then:

- split on either `=` or `:`
- clean by removing `"`, `;` and `,`

This can be done with a generic method as they more or less follow the same format. And the `"code"` field you want is the first one.

```
private static String extract(String[] errorLines, String lineStart) {
    return Arrays.stream(errorLines)
            .map(String::trim) // remove spaces at the beginning
            .filter(s -> s.startsWith(lineStart)) // filter lines starting with the value
            .findFirst()// take the first one
            .map(s -> s.split("[=:]", 2)[1]) // split and take the second half
            .map(s -> s.replaceAll("[;\",]", "")) // remove unwanted characters
            .orElse("");
}
```

Then, `error` being your String:

```
String[] errorLines = error.split("\n");

Stream.of("trackingID", "\"code\":", "\"messages\":", "\"$httpStatus\":")
      .map(s -> extract(errorLines, s))
      .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Outputs:

```
jskdf-77sdkj-oij4-kerj43-lklfds
ABC23423
msg:INVALID_ERROR
400
```